# Caliper missing one boot

Tags: brakes

I'm in the middle of my first break job. Left front went fine, right front I have noticed that in of the rubber boots in the mounting harness for the Caliper is missing. I cannot get a part because its Sunday so I'll have to put it together and drive it for probably 200km's before I can get to put the part in.

I do not want to damage/warp my new rotors or pads in anyway.

A couple of days of driving without the boot wont be a problem will it?

Update: Missing part highlighted on this service manual snippet

[image]

Comment: A photo would be helpful

Comment: I already have the vehicle back together and off the hoist. However I upload the part in the service manual diagram

Comment: What is the year/make/model of the vehicle?

Comment: Mazda 2008/CX-9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should be ok for the trip. Disclaimer: (Taking shortcuts on braking systems is in generally never a good idea, and you should really not trust some random opinion from some internet dude about your safety)

For the medium term you should really get that in order. Chances are that dust and moisture enter and ruin the sliding pins / guides, in consequence the brakes start squealing and in extreme case you can experience less or even no brake effect. There are so called service kits for sale, they contain the rubber boots (part nr. 10), new pins (part nr. 2), new slides  (part nr. 7) and a blister with brake lube. Get one of those (better two) and rework your brakes

Comment: Decent advice. I was thinking of changing the pins also they are not the best looking.